# Что использовать для заполнения и печати типовой формы документа?

Tags: visual-basic

Не могу сориентироваться, что использовать для написания мини-программы для PC, которая принимала бы данные и выводила на печать готовый документ. Вносишь ФИО, данные сопутствующих документов, печатаешь готовый лист А4. Даже считать ничего не надо, просто автозаполнение документа. Подскажите направление, куда копать, что
изучать. Метку ставлю Visual Basic чисто интуитивно.

Comment: Вопрос слишком расплывчат, но посмотрите в сторону JasperReports или FastReport.

Comment: как я понял, простым exe-шником тут не закончится. Клиентская часть, серверная. Надо на выходе простую утилитку получить.

Comment: FastReport работает и из EXE. Но в целом, это лишь направление. Гуглите по ключевым словам дальше )